# Advanced configuration for email notifications about Apple Developer Certificates expiration

Tags: ios, notifications, certificate

Mainly, I just wanted to ask the same question here, because the community here is active (comparing to what is seen on Apple Developer Forums, unfortunately):

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/29994

So in other words, I need to understand **who** in my Developer Program ***receives the email notifications*** about impending expiration of the following:

- iOS Distribution certificate
- Apple Push Services certificates
- APNs Development iOS certificates
- VoIP Services certificates

I want the email notifications from Apple to be sent to specific set of email addresses.

It does not look smart to me sending such email to Team Agent only, since he may miss it (for various reasons) and the app functionality will eventually fail. Definitely this must be received at least by developers who are admins and are responsible for managing Certificates/Profiles on company production servers. I have a distribution list mailbox for all interested parties and would like to subscribe it to those expiration notification emails.

Thanks for your attention.

**UPDATE 03-Jul-2017:**

I have contacted Apple and they replied with this:

> *Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Program Support. I understand
>   from your email that you would like to receive notifications in regard
>   to expiring certificates.*
>
> *By default, the Team Agent is the only person that will receive
>   notifications. At this time Apple does not allow for multiple emails
>   to be notified in regard to expiring certificates.*
>
> *I appreciate that you have taken the time to send us your feedback.
>   Please be assured that all of your comments have been forwarded to the
>   appropriate Apple team so they can be taken into consideration for
>   future enhancements*
>
> *Should you have any further questions, you can reply directly to this
>   email, or if you would like, give us a call:*
>
> *https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php*

Comment: Good point @RAM237! Cannot find any Email Notification settings on my Apple Developer Account settings... but I'm not the Agent. Maybe him can set some more options that normal Admin accounts cannot see.

Comment: Hey @shadowsheep, in fact no. I contacted Apple regarding this and they said there is no way to set any additional emails and I am pretty sure no plans to enhance this. I have updated my question with Apple's response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the certificate on your production servers, you can just monitor them for expiration yourself - you do not need to rely on Apple for this.

Standard server monitoring software such as Nagios (and many, many others) have ready made plugins for exactly this. You can also use simple scripts with the openssl command in a cron to send multiple people an email when it will soon expire.

Comment: Yeah, these are just extra actions which I feel I don't have to do if Apple cared about customers experience a bit more :) Let it be the answer, by the way, since that's what I finally did myself last year.